# Work queue providing retries with increasing delays and the maximum number of attempts. Is a pure RabbitMQ solution possible?

Tags: rabbitmq, scheduled-tasks, worker

I have repetitive tasks that I want to process with a number of workers (i.e., competing consumers pattern). The probability of failure during the task is fairly low so in case of such rare events, I would like to try again after a short period of time, say 1 second.

A sequence of consecutive failures is even less probable but still possible, so for a few initial retries, I would like to stick to a 1-second delay.

However, if the sequence of failures reaches some point, then the most likely there is some external reason that may cause these failures. So from that point, I would like to start extending the delay.

Let's say that the desired distribution of delays looks like this:

```
first appearance in the queue - no delay
retry 1 - 1 second
retry 2 - 1 second
retry 3 - 1 second
retry 4 - 5 second
retry 5 - 10 seconds
retry 6 - 20 seconds
retry 7 - 40 seconds
retry 8 - 80 seconds
retry 9 - 160 seconds
retry 10 - 320 seconds
another retry - drop the message
```

I have found a lot of information about DLXes (Dead Letter Exchanges) that can partially solve the problem. It appears to be easy to achieve an infinite number of retries with the same delay. At the same time, I haven't found a way to increase the delay or to stop after certain number of retries.

I'm looking for the purest RabbitMQ solution possible. However, I'm interested in anything that works.

Comment: If you are in the C# space you could try [Shuttle.Esb](http://shuttle.github.io/shuttle-esb/) which is my open-source service bus.  It has a back-off mechanism built in.  I'm guessing other service bus implementations would be able to do the same.

Comment: Are these potential failures dependent on the message itself or will they cause *all* consecutive messages to fail? Ie could 3 fail while message 4,5,6... work?

Comment: It's possible that N-th try fails and one of the consecutive tries succeeds. Actually, this is the main reason for this mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin available for this. I think you can use it to achieve what you need.
I've used it for something in a similar fashion for handling custom retries with dynamic delays.

[RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin](https://www.rabbitmq.com/blog/2015/04/16/scheduling-messages-with-rabbitmq/)

Answer (score 1):

Using a combination of DLXes and expire/TTL times, you can accomplish this *except* for the case when you want to change the redelivery time, for instance, implementing an exponential backoff.

The only way I could make it work using a pure RabbitMQ approach is to set the expire time to the smallest time needed and then use the [x-death](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) array to figure out how many times the message has been killed and then reject (ie. DLX it again) or ack the message accordingly.

Let's say you set expire time to 1 minute and you need to backoff 1 minute first time, then 5 minutes and then 30 minutes. This translates to x-death.count = 1, followed by 5 and then 30. Any other time you just reject the message.

Note that this can create lots of churn if you have many retry-messages. But if retries are rare, go for it.

Comment: That seems to be helpful. What do you think about the cascade of queues (separate queues for each "retry number")? This way I could set different TTL on each queue and simply do not set DLX on the last one. At the same time, it seems that each retry queue should have a separate queue that I can use to consume messages (it's required to set proper different DLXes). In such an approach, I need to consume from multiple queues and I'm not sure how to do it properly.

Comment: The approach I outline is the one I've used, so I can't really give you any hints wrt cascading queues, excepts that it's a more complex setup so might be hard to keep track of what's going on.